# jQuery plugin for table cell replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a *jQuery plugin* that will take an HTML table, and will allow the **replacement** of cells in between each other, via drag n drop. Example:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

When I drag 1 onto 9, it should replace them like so:

```
[9][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][1]
```

ideally with an optional callback function (to update a remote page with ajax).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is for specific questions, for searching please use [Google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: I wouldn't ask here if I haven't been through the first 50 pages of Google already, trust me. If not a plugin, then at least how to get to it and even try to write it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:
http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

Check the "Switch content option" below the table.

Answer (score 1):

> If not a plugin, then at least how to get to it and even try to write it myself.

Using jQuery UI you can create [draggable elements](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). You can also create [droppable elements](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/).

Try messing around with those demos using a table and table cells and see how far you can get by yourself. If you hit a dead-end, come back and someone may be able to help you out once you have some code!

Answer (score 1):

I've got it! http://jsfiddle.net/8dRZz/

In this example, it will stay "loading" forever, easily understandable since the handler in not there, so no AJAX success call.